# How do I blur background-image but keep hard edges?

Tags: html, css, background-image

[The desired effect (mockup)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysz3h.png).

I masked an image to a button in my form

When I apply a blur to the background-image, I get soft edges on my button, which I do not want.

How can I retain the hard edges of the button and also have the text appear on top?

View the Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PWpMpX

**HTML**

```
   <form>
     <!-- Inputs not shown -->
    <button id="gButton">Preview Album &raquo;</button>
  </form>
```

**CSS**

```
button#gButton{
  display: block;
  width: 280px;
  height: 42px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 11px;
  background-color: #B08DC0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;

  /*Background Image Stuff Below*/
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/35/Flume_-_Skin.png);

  background-size: 140%;
  background-position: center;

  -webkit-background-clip: content-box;
  background-clip: content-box;

  color: rgba(0,0,0,0);

  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px); 
}

form{
  width: 280px; 
  margin:0 auto; 
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px; 
}
```

Comment: First of all, separate text and background - if you blur the element, you blur the text content as well. Suggest you wrap the button content in an additional span, and position a pseudo element on the button behind the span, to hold the blurry background. overflow:hidden should keep the edges sharp within the rounded button corners.

Comment: @CBroe Ahh! Thanks! I'll try that now.

Comment: Please check this link:-https://css-tricks.com/the-blur-up-technique-for-loading-background-images/ May be it will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend moving the background image to a pseudo-element.

```css
button {
    width: 280px;
    height: 42px;
    
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #B08DC0;
    border-radius: 11px;
    color: #fff;
}

button::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    
    /* Background... */
    background-image: url(//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/35/Flume_-_Skin.png);
    background-size: 140%;
    background-position: center;
    background-clip: content-box;
    filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<button>Some Text</button>
```

You can play around with having the width/height of the psuedo-element be larger than 100%. You'd just have to adjust the top/left offsets. This way, you can remove what looks like a "glow" around the edges of the image.